# Tag Aggregation Data index process unknown error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, magento-1.9

I seem to be having an issues indexing on Magento. All available indexes index fine except for one:

> Tag Aggregation Data

When indexing through the following error, but I can't quite see what the issue is.

```
Tag Aggregation Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'COUNT(tr.customer_id) + MIN(IF(tp.base_popularity IS NOT NULL, tp.base_popularity, 0))' in 'field list'' in /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#5 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#6 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Resource/Indexer/Summary.php(233): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ma...')
#7 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Resource/Indexer/Summary.php(135): Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Indexer_Summary->aggregate()
#8 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Indexer_Summary->reindexAll()
#9 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'COUNT(tr.customer_id) + MIN(IF(tp.base_popularity IS NOT NULL, tp.base_popularity, 0))' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `magentotag_summary` (`tag_id`, `store_id`, `customers`, `products`, `popularity`, `uses`, `historical_uses`, `base_popularity`) SELECT `tr`.`tag_id`, `tr`.`store_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT tr.customer_id) AS `customers`, COUNT(DISTINCT tr.product_id) AS `products`, `COUNT(tr.customer_id) + MIN(IF(tp.base_popularity IS NOT NULL, tp`.`base_popularity, 0))` AS `popularity`, 0 AS `uses`, 0 AS `historical_uses`, 0 AS `base_popularity` FROM `magentotag_relation` AS `tr`
 INNER JOIN `magentocore_store` AS `cs` ON cs.store_id = tr.store_id
 INNER JOIN `magentocatalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON cs.website_id = pw.website_id AND tr.product_id = pw.product_id
 INNER JOIN `magentocatalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON tr.product_id = e.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `magentotag_properties` AS `tp` ON tp.tag_id = tr.tag_id AND tp.store_id = tr.store_id
 INNER JOIN `magentocatalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 273 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `magentocatalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 273 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id
 INNER JOIN `magentocatalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_visibility` ON tad_visibility.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_visibility.attribute_id = 526 AND tad_visibility.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `magentocatalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_visibility` ON tas_visibility.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_visibility.attribute_id = 526 AND tas_visibility.store_id = cs.store_id
 INNER JOIN `magentocataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = e.entity_id AND ciss.website_id = cs.website_id WHERE (tr.active = 1) AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1) AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_visibility.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_visibility.value, tad_visibility.value)!=1) AND (ciss.stock_status = 1) GROUP BY `tr`.`tag_id`,
        `tr`.`store_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tag_id` = VALUES(`tag_id`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `customers` = VALUES(`customers`), `products` = VALUES(`products`), `popularity` = VALUES(`popularity`), `uses` = VALUES(`uses`), `historical_uses` = VALUES(`historical_uses`), `base_popularity` = VALUES(`base_popularity`)' in /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#4 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#5 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Resource/Indexer/Summary.php(233): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ma...')
#6 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Resource/Indexer/Summary.php(135): Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Indexer_Summary->aggregate()
#7 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Indexer_Summary->reindexAll()
#8 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#9 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#10 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#11 /mywebsite-domain/httpd.www/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#12 {main}
```

Any clues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The faulty backticks are inserted because Zend_Db_Select->_tableCols() fails to detect `COUNT(tr.customer_id) + MIN(IF(tp.base_popularity IS NOT NULL, tp.base_popularity, 0))` as some SQL function, which should pass it to `Zend_Db_Expr()` then. Instead, it is detected as [currentCorrelationName].[col] and then handled as ordinary string.

A fix for this issue is to loosen the regular expression for detecting SQL functions:

Open `lib/Zend/Db/Select.php`, find the following line and remove the string end symbol ($):

```
const REGEX_COLUMN_EXPR = '/^([\w]*\(([^\(\)]|(?1))*\))$/';
```

... so it looks like this one:

```
const REGEX_COLUMN_EXPR = '/^([\w]*\(([^\(\)]|(?1))*\))/';
```

Now, `Zend_Db_Select->_tableCols()` should pass the whole expression to `Zend_Db_Expr()`, and the SQL error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is an indexing error. If you carefully check the select part of the `insert ... select ...` statement, then you can see that the expression `COUNT(tr.customer_id) + MIN(IF(tp.base_popularity IS NOT NULL, tp`.`base_popularity, 0))` is enclosed by backticks (`), which means that mysql tries to interpret this as a name of a column and not as an expression. Obviously, there is no such column, hence the error message. Remove the backticks around this expression and the error message will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. @Shadow There are no backquote in Summary.php

```
/**
 * Aggregate tags by specified ids
 *
 * @param null|int|array $tagIds
 * @return Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Indexer_Summary
 */
public function aggregate($tagIds = null)
{
    $writeAdapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    $this->beginTransaction();

    try {
        if (!empty($tagIds)) {
            $writeAdapter->delete(
                $this->getTable('tag/summary'), array('tag_id IN(?)' => $tagIds)
            );
        } else {
            $writeAdapter->delete($this->getTable('tag/summary'));
        }

        $select = $writeAdapter->select()
            ->from(
                array('tr' => $this->getTable('tag/relation')),
                array(
                    'tr.tag_id',
                    'tr.store_id',
                    'customers'         => 'COUNT(DISTINCT tr.customer_id)',
                    'products'          => 'COUNT(DISTINCT tr.product_id)',
                    'popularity'        => 'COUNT(tr.customer_id) + MIN('
                        . $writeAdapter->getCheckSql(
                            'tp.base_popularity IS NOT NULL',
                            'tp.base_popularity',
                            '0'
                            )
                        . ')',
                    'uses'              => new Zend_Db_Expr(0), // deprecated since 1.4.0.1
                    'historical_uses'   => new Zend_Db_Expr(0), // deprecated since 1.4.0.1
                    'base_popularity'   => new Zend_Db_Expr(0)  // deprecated since 1.4.0.1
                )
            )
```

Hope someone has solution to this. Tried almost everything.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same SQL error, in a Magento 1.9.2.4. Did you find a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this on a clients site, brand new install, basically a base 1.9.3.2 install

here is what I have found:

The site uses composer (of course) to install some base packages.

One of them is this:

`colinmollenhour/magento-redis-session": "^2.0"`

That in turn loads dependencies

`- Installing magento/zendframework1 (1.12.16-patch3) Downloading: 100% Extracting archive
    REASON: colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.3.1 requires magento/zendframework1 ~1.12.0 -> satisfiable by magento/zendframework1[1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.10, 1.12.13, 1.12.16, 1.12.16-patch1, 1.12.16-patch2, 1.12.16-patch3, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.12.4, 1.12.5, 1.12.6, 1.12.7, 1.12.8, 1.12.9, 1.12.9-patch1].`

So,an update to magento/zendframework1 is installed into vendor. At this time installed was 'magento/zendframework1:1.12.16-patch3'

Once I removed the redis-session composer packages, which removed the zend update, things returned to normal.

`Removals: colinmollenhour/magento-redis-session, colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract, magento/zendframework1, colinmollenhour/credis
  - Removing colinmollenhour/magento-redis-session (2.0.2)
  - Removing colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract (v1.3.1)
  - Removing magento/zendframework1 (1.12.16-patch3)
  - Removing colinmollenhour/credis (1.7)`

The composer entry for package install was set to install version 2.0 >
Looking at the package releases (https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession/releases)

v1.12 was marked as: The last release before switching to the Magento 2 compatible version.

Locking down composer to that version: `"colinmollenhour/magento-redis-session": "1.12"`

solves the problem, and retains redis-session update into magento codebase.

*So, basically, issue is that redis-session > 1.12 is not m1 compatible.*

Comment: happy days: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession/issues/105#issuecomment-284162608